# Reshape numpy массива Python

Tags: python

Есть ли какое встроенное средств, позволяющее сделать корректное преобразование массива вида `[100, 100, 4]` к `[4, 100, 100]`. Простое `np.reshape()` выдает некорректный результат.

Comment: вам нужно жлементы в обратном порядке расставить? или отсортировать?

Comment: есть изображение в 100х100 с 4 каналами - получаю [100, 100, 4], требуется  [4, 100, 100]

Comment: @lao712, добавьте тогда свой ответ -- чтобы вопрос не висел как без ответа

Answer (score 1):

ответ

```
np.rollaxis(array, 2).reshape(3, width, height)
```